# Writing a multipaged tif file from memorystream vs filestream?

Tags: c#, tiff, libtiff.net

I am trying to use a `LibTiff.Net` library and rewriting a merge tool `TiffCP` api to use memory streams.

This library has a `Tiff` class and by passing a stream to this class, it can merge tiff images into this stream.

For testing, I passed on a `Filestream` and I got what i wanted - it merged and I was able to see multipage tif.

But when I pass a `MemoryStream`, I am able to verify that the page data is being added to the stream as I loop through but when I write it to the file at the end, I could see only 1st page.

```
var mso = new MemoryStream();
var fso = new FileStream(@"C:\test\ttest.tif",FileMode.OpenOrCreate); //This works
using (Tiff outImage = Tiff.ClientOpen("custom", "w", mso, tso))
{
 //...
 //..
 System.Drawing.Image tiffImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mso, true);
 tiffImg.Save(@"C:\test\test2.tiff", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
 tiffImg.Dispose();
 //..
 //..
}
```

P.S: I need it in memorystream because, of some folder permissions on servers + vendor API reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably using the memory stream before data is actually written into the stream.

Please use `Tiff.Flush()` method before accessing data in the memory stream. And please make sure you call `Tiff.WriteDirectory()` method for each page you create.

**EDIT:**

Please also take a look at Bob Powell's article on [Generating Multi-Page TIFF files](https://web.archive.org/web/20141223070416/http://bobpowell.net/generating_multipage_tiffs.aspx). The article shows how to use `EncoderParameter`s to actually generate a multipage TIFF.

Using

```
tiffImg.Save(@"C:\test\test2.tiff", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
```

you are probably save only first frame.

Comment: I am using both functions, I even checked with this fso.Write(mso.GetBuffer(), 0, mso.GetBuffer().Length); and when I use a filestream I can see two pages. As you can see I am just reading from the memory stream. But when I write it like System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mso, true); it writes only first page.